# Can't create unittests IntelliJ

Tags: maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I am not able to select my testfolder in IntelliJ.
For some reason it wasn't there when I created this project, so I added it manually. After I did that, I went to project structure --> modules, where I marked it as a test.

I am simply not allowed to leave my source directory, when creating a testcase.

See image:

[image: Image showing the error]

The problem doesn't occure when I create a new project, where the testfolder is set automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have wrong project structure.

It should be as follows:

```
project-name
    |-- pom.xml
    |-- src
        |-- main
        |    |-- java
        |    |-- resources
        |-- test
             |-- java
             |-- resources
```

And don't mark the `test` directory as a *test source root*. You should mark the `test/`**`java`** (subdirectory under the `test` folder) instead:

[image]